# Programmatically marking an Oracle BPEL task complete

Tags: java, oracle, bpel

I am using Oracle BPEL Process manager and have a task assigned to a group of users. 
I try to mark it approved using Java class oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.ITaskService.updateTaskOutcome(). This works if the task is assigned to an individual user, but if the task is assigned to a group of users, I get an error message about the task not being acquired.

If I acquire the task using oracle.bpel.services.workflow.task.ITaskService.acquireTask(), I get an error message when trying to mark it approved: "The task has been acquired by some other user".

Can anybody point to sample code that changes status of an Oracle BPEL task *assigned to a group* programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

use `updateTaskOutcomes()` method instead of `updateTaskOutcome()` when it is assigned to multiple users

Comment: I don't see such a method in oracle.bpel.services.workflow.tas.ITaskService (for Javadoc, see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12483_01/integrate.1013/b28985/oracle/bpel/services/workflow/task/ITaskService.html). Is this a method on some other class? If so, which? Could you provide a link to the Javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem seems obvious, you cannot approve a task that it is assigned to a group without first acquiring. Otherwise, which member of the group had approved the task?

Your second problem is that you are acquiring the task with one user and trying to approve it with another user.

To actually find where the problem is, you can acquire the task and then go to the meta db and search who has acquired the task. I guess that will give you a better picture of what is actually happening.